Counter for SNS likes (e.g. on Facebook)
So, a very quick question for those who know it, but for me it grew into several more related matters. My first guess was that you can use ~個, e.g. "I got over a thousand likes!" would be 「いいね！」を1000個以上をもらった！
So, one more question arose right away: which verb is usually used in this case? I decided to check what Google Translate has to say (I know not to trust it, but it can provide at least some useful input), and one of the translations it offered is 1000件以上の「いいね！」をいただきました！
So, again, it seems quite logical in retrospect to use 件 since one of its meanings is "occurrence" (my second guess was actually 回). Some field study proved that in real/spoken Japanese counters can be omitted. For example, here, it says:

新しくアップした写真に100イイネもついてる！

(Also, イイネ is written like that to accentuate the specific usage, I guess)
Some other examples showed that you actually can use もらう, so the only question I have left is the initial one, with possible solutions, considering all the input I had:

Don't use any counters (I guess it's OK in casual speech), i.e. 「いいね！」を1000以上もらった！ or, for example, 1000以上のイイネをもらった！
Use 件 if it's more formal (and maybe use a more formal/polite verb as well), i.e. 会社の新しい投稿は「いいね！」を1000件以上いただきました。


Here are possible options:

いいね: People commonly use いいね and other similar reactions as units. 1000いいねが付いた, 3000リポストされた, 500ふぁぼ貰った (favs), 3ダウンボートされた, etc. This style is generally avoided in formal or academic contexts, though.
No counter/unit: いいねが1000ついた, リツイートが3000行った, etc.
回: 1000回いいねされた, リツイートが3000回に届いた, etc.
個: While perfectly understandable, this is not the most common option.
件: This counter is mainly used for distinct items such as articles, comments, issues, contracts, and projects. Although not unnatural, it may sound overly technical or formal in casual situations.

I recommend using the first three options.
As for verb choices, ついた and された are neutral verbs, whereas もらった implies gratitude. いただいた is a humble verb used specifically to express gratitude.

+1, but note that many (if not most) platforms actually use 件 as official counters for reactions.

@broccoliforest Thanks, indeed, 件 has a feel of technical or official documentation.

Thank you for such a detailed reply and mentioning all the nuances!

IMO omission is the most common way. I'd say both 個 and 件 can be used, but 件 has the slight nuance that there is some variation or content in each いいね, which isn't the case so I'd say 個 sounds more correct.
This is why one should rather say 100件のコメント rather than 100個のコメント because in this case they do vary. But in a context where you purposefully do not care about the variation among them, you can use 個, e.g. 「なんでもいいからコメント１００個とってこい」
PS: And maybe this is why some companies rather use 件 for いいね, as it shows appreciation for the individuals behind each いいね.

Thank you for all the details about how each of these might be interpreted, it's really interesting and useful!
